# Since Scala lists are immutable, are they actually traversed at run-time for operations, length, last or xs(n)?

Tags: scala, list

Until now I thought a list had to be traversed to count the length of it or get the last element.

Then I thought "since it is immutable, the length or last element, or any element for that sake, are all constant, so maybe some work could be saved by storing those in pointers on creation of a list".

If I have a list xs and use xs.length, and later on I use xs.length again, will the list be traversed twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the list is traversed with every call to length.

The thing about `List` is that there is no "manager" container to store all that information.  A reference to a list is actually a reference to the first node of that list, and it only knows about it's own data element and the next node in the list.  You could come up with a mechanism to cache that information but it would increase the overhead of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes.  It depends on which implementation of `List` you are talking about.  Most of the `List`'s are defined as recursive data structures, eg `head :: (tail:List)`  I think `ListBuffer` has a constant time lookup for `length`

The [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) detail the performance of typical operations.

Comment: in the Scala collections, `List` is `scala.collection.immutable.List` which is a concrete collection type. it doesn't have multiple implementations. perhaps you are thinking of thinking of `java.util.List`, which is different.